# SourceBuffer.appendBuffer() fails when client joins in the middle of live-stream

Tags: javascript, socket.io, video-streaming, video-capture, live-streaming

I'm making a simple video live-streaming site. My basic implementation is to record fragments of webcam video using MediaRecorder, and send them to the server using socket.io. Then, the server broadcasts the fragments back to all the other clients, where they are reconstructed using MediaSource and SourceBuffer and passed into the video.

This works when the client is already connected to the server when the stream begins, but if the client joins in the middle of streaming (meaning they only being receiving fragments from the middle of the video) the appendBuffer() fails and MediaSource closes.

I've tried finding a solution with no luck. I think it had to do with the encoding of the passed fragments, and you can't just start with a fragment from the middle of the recording, but I can't find a workaround to this issue. Would really appreciate the assistance. The relevant parts of my code are here:

```
function Stream(cam) {
  //record video in chunks, send over websocket
  this.cameraStream = null;

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }).then((stream) => {
    this.cameraStream = stream;
    switch (cam) {
      case 1:
        video1.srcObject = stream;
        video1.play();
        break;
      case 2:
        video2.srcObject = stream;
        video2.play();
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    if (cam !== null) record(stream, delayMS);
  });

  var record = (stream, ms) => {
    var rec = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
      mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs="opus,vp8"',
    });
    rec.start(ms);
    rec.ondataavailable = (e) => {
      var fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = () => {
        socket.emit('stream-frag', {
          stream: fileReader.result,
          room: window.location.pathname.split('/')[0] || '/',
          cam: cam,
        });
      };
      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.data);
    };
  };

  this.endStream = function () {
    cam = null;
    cameraStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
  };
}

function getStream() {
  //recieve video chunks from server
  socket.on('stream-frag', (data) => {
    //console.log(stream);
    switch (data.cam) {
      case 1:
        if (
          mediaSource1.readyState === 'open' &&
          sourceBuffer1 &&
          sourceBuffer1.updating === false
        ) {
          sourceBuffer1.appendBuffer(data.stream);
          if (sourceBuffer1.buffered.length > 0) video1.play();
        }
        break;
      case 2:
        if (
          mediaSource2.readyState === 'open' &&
          sourceBuffer2 &&
          sourceBuffer2.updating === false
        ) {
          sourceBuffer2.appendBuffer(data.stream);
          if (sourceBuffer2.buffered.length > 0) video2.play();
        }
        break;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to stop the record. you can to set a timeout to create chunks of video that you will concatenate in server using ffmpeg.